# Questions about "stateless, layered multi-threaded rendering"

Tags: architecture, rendering

I have read this blog:

https://blog.molecular-matters.com/2014/12/16/stateless-layered-multi-threaded-rendering-part-3-api-design-details/

Where does a setup like this bind textures/buffers and does state(shaders, blend, rasterizer) switching?
Wouldn't that mean that is anything but stateless when i submit a command only for drawing? Drawing Command would expect correct state, wouldn't it?

Comment: I think the execution of the command puts the GPU into the correct state for that command. The state is not saved between commands, that's what they mean by stateless.

Comment: but that would mean every command sets the state. that is very costly

Comment: Is setting the state to the same state that it already is costly? If so, then just remember the last state you set, and don't set it if it's the same.